# Image caching problem in webView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, uiwebview

I am making an iPhone app.

I am creating an image out of the graph and then embedding it into HTML to display the image into webView using `loadHTMLString:baseURL:` method.

Now the image is shown fine for the first time.

When I make changes into the graph and the image is recaptured it still shows the old image.

So basically it does not update the image. The image name is same and the older image is deleted from the Documents directory but it still somehow shows the old image.

How can I remove this kind of caching of images in webView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I solved this problem was to add timestamp along with image name so that everytime the imagename that gets generated is unique. This way it always fetches correct image.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I know to avoid image caching in local html pages is to embed them directly into the [html or css](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/)

Answer (score 0):

It is the cache in webkit that leads to your problem .

To solve it, you may have to do something with the http-protocol. That is to say, you should set the correct cache-related header of your http response, such as `Expires`, `Age`, `Cache-Control`, `Last-Modified`. After that, webkit will no longer cache the images for your.

If you do not have the permission to modify header on server, you may use `NSURLProtocol` to intercept the response before it's sent to webkit.

key code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
    NSHTTPURLResponse *httpRes = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response;
    NSMutableDictionary *headers = [[httpRes allHeaderFields] mutableCopy];
    [headers removeObjectForKey:@"Expires"];
    [headers removeObjectForKey:@"Cache-Control"];
    [headers removeObjectForKey:@"Age"];
    [headers removeObjectForKey:@"Last-Modified"];
    NSHTTPURLResponse *newRes = [[NSHTTPURLResponse alloc] initWithURL:[[connection originalRequest] URL]
                                                            statusCode:[httpRes statusCode]
                                                           HTTPVersion:@"HTTP/1.1"
                                                          headerFields:[headers copy]
                                 ];

    [self.client URLProtocol:self didReceiveResponse:[newRes copy] cacheStoragePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed];

}
```

Ref :

- Caching in HTTP : http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.2.3
- Tutorial of NSURLProtocol: http://devmonologue.com/ios/tutorials/nsurlprotocol-tutorial/